# MVP andoid и поворот экрана, использование ViewModel

Tags: java, android, mvp, activity-life-cycle, viewmodel

Задался я вопросом как быть при повороте экрана, если ты используешь паттерн архитектуры MVP. Увидел много советов использовать для этого Moxy. Но у Google ведь есть прекрасный инструмент ViewModel LifeCycle, который живет, пока живет твоя активити. Собственно хочу задать вопрос, нормально ли например прикрепить к активити ViewModel, и передать ссылку на объект ViewModel в презентер? Далее через  презентер сохранять в ViewModel данные, которые нужно сохранить при повороте экрана. В презентере проверять на наличие этих данных и соответственно возвращать из ViewModel LifeCycle сохраненые данные при повороте экрана. И не делать например сетевые запросы или обращение к базе данных в модели.

Приведу кусочек примера:
ViewModel

```
public class VModel extends ViewModel
{
   private PhotoDay vmPhotoDay = null;       

    public PhotoDay getVmPhotoDay() {
        return vmPhotoDay;
    }

    public void setVmPhotoDay(PhotoDay vmPhotoDay) {
        this.vmPhotoDay = vmPhotoDay;
    }   

}
введите сюда код
```

В MainActivity

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MainContract.IMainView {

        private MainContract.IMainPresenter iMainPresenter;
        private ImageView pDay;
        private ProgressBar progressBar;
        private VModel vModel;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            pDay = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photoDay);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

            vModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(VModel.class);
            iMainPresenter = new MainPresenter(this, vModel);

            iMainPresenter.onShow();
        }
@Override
    public void showPhotoDay(PhotoDay photoDay) {

        Picasso.get()
               .load(photoDay.getUrl())
               .resize(300, 350)
               .into(pDay);

    }
    }
```

В презентере MainPresenter

```
public class MainPresenter implements MainContract.IMainPresenter {

    private MainContract.IMainView iMainView;
    private IModelDannie iModelDannie;    

    private VModel vModel;

    public MainPresenter(MainContract.IMainView iMainView, VModel vModel)
    {
        this.iMainView = iMainView;
        iModelDannie = new ModelDannie();
        this.vModel = vModel;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShow() {

        iMainView.showProgressBar();

        if(vModel.getVmPhotoDay()==null){
        iModelDannie.getPhotoDay().subscribe((PhotoDay photoDay)->
        {
            if(photoDay!=null) {
                iMainView.showPhotoDay(photoDay);
                vModel.setVmPhotoDay(photoDay);

            }else
            {
                iMainView.message(R.string.error_image);
            }
        });
        }else
        {
            iMainView.showPhotoDay(vModel.getVmPhotoDay());
        }
    }    

}
```

Можно ли так делать?

Comment: Это Бородино какое-то.. Выберите что-то одно MVP или MVVM, зачем P и VM одновременно ?

Comment: ViewModel Lificycle и View Model в MVVM это же разные вещи. Или нет?

Comment: Если второе это элемент паттерна проектирования, то первое почти ничто - выдумка, разумеется, если в ViewModel объект инстанцируется в активити или фрагменте, то его жизненный цикл (как и у любого класса) связан этим родительским объектом и мало понятно, что дает нечто названное ViewModel Lificycle и не имеющее содержания, потому как любой объект созданный в активити будет иметь Object Lificycle.

Comment: Естественно, можно создать такой ViewModel  Lificycle и привязать его к активити Lificycle. На одном on-методе активити создается объект ViewModel  , на другом - считывает или создает стартовое состояние модели, которое отрисуется  во view и т.д.

Comment: ну я про этот ViewModel https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?gclid=Cj0KCQiAxfzvBRCZARIsAGA7YMw0ytLA7oJL6OTvyvAeqEjOQ3JlK8Wccu5iX0xNJY2U2wEqvn03lOwaAqJSEALw_wcB